# My app makes certain devices reset

Tags: android

I have a report that my app makes certain devices reset (reboot).

I have no idea how can an app possibly make a device reset (I don't use the Admin classes, and don't have that permission).
The app involves standard UI + JNI calls + some OpenGL ES 2 rendering.
My best guess is that a GLSL shader freaks out the device...

When a device resets it erases its LogCat buffer as well.

Any advice on what and where to look for?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are right regarding that it's something using OpenGL. However, there is also some probability that it's something related to JNI (especially, if you are doing something beyond the basic calls).

I think the only way of actions is following:

- gather info on which devices, OS version it happens
- get a device to reproduce it or get in touch with a user who can do some testing for you
- prepare a version which logs to a file (and dont' forget to flush a file after each line of log, else reset will kill a buffered logs)
- wrap all suspicious places into logs